# How to time the execution of multiple queries in PHPMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

For my search I use multiple queries and I wanted to measure how long it takes mySQL to execute them all. PHPMyAdmin runs all the queries you give it, but It only give the results and execution time of the last one. Is there any way to see a combined execution time without getting out my calculator? :)

Answer (score 0):

```
select @a := now();

...

select @b := now();
select timediff(@b, @a);
```

Comment: it works a treat... except that timediff only measures in minimum seconds.... I have to execute my multiple queries, multiple times to get 1 second. Any way to get a lower measurement?